# Typescript - "SourceMap file read failed" when running solution in VS2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript, tsc

I encounter some weird issue when launching my TypeScript solutions (it happens even with the default solution which comes along with a new TypeScript project in visual-studio). Sometimes (it happens very often), when i launch my TypeScript solution (with IE), it takes quite a while to load (i just get a blank white page for a while (for around 10-15 seconds), and after that the homepage is loaded). In the output window of VS2013, i can see that the reason for that is because there was a timeout in reading few of the source-map files (image is attached).

[image]

Does anyone knows why it happens? Ever happened to anyone? it is very annoying... :(
Any help will be much appreciated.

**I'm using Win8 / VS2013 / TS 0.9.5 / IIS Express.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ideas I have for you...

-Verify the .js.map file exists.

-Initiate a new WebClient object for the next request rather than trying to reuse the object.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/c0e2fdde-c5fc-4ff2-8ac5-ba4a254c0a23/webclient-does-not-support-concurrent-io-operations?forum=wpdevelop

[WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755623/webclient-does-not-support-concurrent-i-o-operations)

Comment: I have no control over any WebClient object... I just run the TS solution from VS2013, which probably creates such object at debug-time. Am I missing something? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some error in Visual Studio 2013 after debugging for a while. I have restarted Visual Studio and it is gone.

Edit: I have also noticed this happening when JavaScript runtime exception happens (see Output window of VS). Then fixing the JavaScript and then restarting Visual Studio helped.

Comment: Tried it as well... doesn't really help :-(

Comment: Updated with JS runtime exceptions, might worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but as i stated, it also happens to me when i just start a fresh new typescript project (which is populated with Microsoft's Greeter demo files). I don't think there is any JS exception over there...